# Jquery datepicker in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

Im making a wordpress plugin but when I use the code to use Jquery it doesnt work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://iqamah.org/PrayTimes.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I want to use this(http://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/279/) datepicker in the backend wordpress.

I can only see an input box, but when I click it nothing happens.

Comment: are you using wp best practices to register scripts? Are you familiar with jQuery.noConflict() that is used in wordpress? What errors get thrown?

Comment: no I am not. I have used  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker'); but still they dont work

Comment: Are those scripts loading? what errors get thrown?

Answer (score 1):

there are already plugins available for datepicker in wordpress.
You can use it them. 
one of good date picker plugin is "WP datepicker".

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-datepicker/

Comment: Great plugin, i used it one of my projects.